# How to add two vertical lines in LyX

Tags: lyx

I need to do two vertical lines in LyX like this:

[image: Two vertical lines]

How to do that?

Comment: According to the [LyX wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX16#commands) it is `Ctrl+Return`.

Comment: This shortcut produce me only a line break.

Comment: I only know how to write it in LaTeX: `\left\| \begin{array}{l} \textit{For~} a \\ f(a') \\ \end{array} \right.`

Comment: Or in text-mode `\begin{tabular}{||l} \textit{For} $a$ \\ $f(a')$ \\ \end{tabular}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have an equivalent of the LaTeX `\left\| \begin{array}{l} \mbox{For } a \\ f(a') \\ \end{array} \right.`

First, you go I̲nsert>Math̲>Delimiter̲s

You uncheck the box "Keep matched" and you chose the correct left and right:
[image: Delimiters]

Then, inside these delimiters, you will be in maths mode and have access to the maths toolbar. Add a matrix 2x1:
[image]

Finally, you may want to use a \mbox for your "For ", Lyx should auto-complete.

Fill the matrix with the wanted elements, and you get:

[image: Result]

You could also use `\textit` instead of the `\mbox` and have:

[image: Result2]

Answer (score 1):

You could use some ERT (type `<CTRL+l>` for that, thats '`l`' like in **l**atex) and insert `\vline{}~\vline{}` into its box (thats LaTeX code for 'vertical line', 'space', 'vertical line'). 
Move out of the ERT box and write your math to the right of it.

The lines on the left will be the same height as your math on the right of it.